# dereferencing pointer that was cast to double pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I am having some trouble understanding these two lines of code.

```
T* Result = Free;
Free = *((T**)Free);
```

Where T is a template class and Free is defined as;

```
T* Free;
```

Is it just creating a new pointer to some other memory address?

http://jfdube.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/memory-management-part-2-allocations-tracking/

This is the context, in the Freelist class within the New() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Free = *((T**)Free);
```

I think this could be more clearly written as:

```
Free = (T *) *Free;
```

Both statements rely on undefined behavior, treating a `T` as a `T *` pointer. Conceptually, what's they're doing is assigning `*Free` to `Free`. For example, if `T` were `int`, then the statement reinterprets an `int` as a pointer to `int` assigns it overtop of the original pointer.

As to what kind of sense this makes, that depends on the larger context. The code is sketchy; it could be genius or it could be foolishness.

Comment: http://jfdube.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/memory-management-part-2-allocations-tracking/ This is the context, in relation to the Freelist class. in New()